# Add a VLAN for virtual machines to Tomato USB

Tags: router, ip, routing, tomato, vlan

I've got an ASUS RTAC66U with Tomato Shibby 1.28 v115 installed.

I've got some VMs with which I'm trying to replicate a set of servers, down to IP address to debug some stuff.

I've set the VMs to use a static IP address but they don't have internet access. I believe I need to configure another VLAN on my router and bridge it with the other VLANs but I've got no idea.

How do I add a VLAN to Tomato USB so that my VMs with IPs in the range 192.168.12.2-254 will be visible from the other VLANs and have internet access?

Bonus points for explanation.

Comment: See if this link helps. http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/how-to-set-up-a-vlan-on-tomato.65405/